# Proof of limit of a sequence where n approaches infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

[image]

I understand all of the proof until I get to the part where we divide by 2M. My teacher explained that we divide by 2M because we are aiming to get to epsilon, which makes sense but this does not seem vigorous enough to me as I believe that dividing by 2M, can potentially effect the inequality sign?

Is there a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

The inequality signs would not change since $M>0$.

Since $X = (x_n)$ is convergenging to $a$ and $Y = (y_n)$ is converging to $b$. For arbitrary $\epsilon_2 > 0$, we can find $K_1, K_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$n > K_1$ then we have $|x_n-a|<\epsilon_2$ and
$n > K_2$ then we have $|y_n-b|<\epsilon_2$.

Now, we just have to let $\epsilon_2 =\frac{\epsilon}{2M}>0$.

Comment: So basically, epsilon can take on any arbitrary value?

Comment: yes, arbitrary positive value.